# I want to get values inside the span ex: 3 6 9 7 5 8 2 4 6 7 1 2 8 7 7 2 4 8 0 9

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="digits" class="digits">
  <span class="digits_moved_down">3</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">6</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">9</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">5</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">8</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">2</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">4</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">6</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">1</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">2</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">8</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">2</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">4</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">8</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">0</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">9</span>
```

I want to get values inside the span ex: 3 6 9 7 5 8 2 4 6 7 1 2 8 7 7 2 4 8 0 9

- List item

---

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

To get the output as a `list`, try using a CSS Selector to select class names that start with `digits_moved` :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'html.parser')

result = [tag.text for tag in soup.select('.digits [class^="digits_moved"]')]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['3', '6', '9', '7', '5', '8', '2', '4', '6', '7', '1', '2', '8', '7', '7', '2', '4', '8', '0', '9']
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div id="digits" class="digits">
  <span class="digits_moved_down">3</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">6</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">9</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">5</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">8</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">2</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">4</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">6</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">1</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">2</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">8</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">7</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">2</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">4</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">8</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_up">0</span>
  <span class="digits_moved_down">9</span>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

spans = soup.find('div', class_ = "digits").find_all('span')

[print(span.text) for span in spans]
```

Output:

```
3
6
9
7
5
8
2
4
6
7
1
2
8
7
7
2
4
8
0
9
```

If you want all the numbers in one line, then replace the last line with this:

```
[print(span.text, end = " ") for span in spans]
```

Output:

```
3 6 9 7 5 8 2 4 6 7 1 2 8 7 7 2 4 8 0 9
```